# Can anyone provide a definition for "find" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs

This context comes from the book "Black Rednecks And White Liberals" by Thomas Sowell

*"Both in Brazil and in the United States—the countries with the two largest slave populations in the Western Hemisphere—the end of slavery **found** the regions in which slaves had been concentrated poorer than other regions of these same countries."*

discover or experience to be the case. (Oxford-Languages)

*"the majority of staff find the magazine to be informative and useful"*

It's hard for me to find a proper definition for "find" in this context, even though I think I saw it once somewhere.

Comment: 6. VERB If a time or event finds you in a particular situation, you are in that situation at the time mentioned or when the event occurs. _Daybreak found us on a cold, clammy ship. His lunch did not take long to arrive and found him poring over his notepad_ [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/find)

Comment: "Coincided with", as in:  "The end of slavery _coincided with_ the regions ... being poorer."  "Found" is used figuratively.  "Saw" would be a synonym:  "The end of slavery _saw_ the regions ... poorer."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Isn't that an answer?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - it is my habit to provide comments, and not answers, to poor quality questions like this one, probably carried over from English Language and Usage. Lack of research.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Got it, that makes sense. I find this question OK, since OP did provide one definition (showing some research effort, at least) and because this is not a very easy meaning to search for. I see what you're saying, though.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - on ELU perfectly good answers get downvotes to discourage answers to poor quality questions.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan  I admit that I didn't put as much effort into research as I could (I'm having a busy time at work recently) but sometimes, I do and even then I get downvotes for the post. How can I prevent that? I mean this is a language-learning forum after all. I can't promise a perfect vocabulary and style and entertainment value. I though it was because of the title fo the book but apparently, it's not the case.

Comment: @StaticBounce I can't tell you exactly how much research everyone expects, since it varies from person to person. I'd say enough to demonstrate that you've made a decent, reasonable effort at finding the answer yourself. I recommend searching [the Meta site](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/) for discussions of this topic (for example: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3531/an-emerging-pattern-of-research-close-votes) and, if those posts don't help, asking yourself on Meta.

Answer (score 2):

**Find**
6. VERB If a time or event finds you in a particular situation, you are in that situation at the time mentioned or when the event occurs.

Daybreak found us on a cold, clammy ship.

His lunch did not take long to arrive and found him poring over his notepad [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/find) –
Michael Harvey